# RotativaPDF css not working on server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rotativa

I have one reports, and it usually works in localhost with css.
But when I put on the server does not load css with bundle.

code :

```
public ActionResult ParseSendPDF()
{
    var result = Session["Search"] as List<Order>;
    ViewAsPdf pdf = new ViewAsPdf("SendPDF", result);
    pdf.PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape;
    pdf.PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4;
    pdf.CustomSwitches = "--background";
    foreach (var results in result)
    {
        foreach (var detail in results.OrderDetails)
        {
             var description = detail.Description;
             if (description.Length > 84)
             {
                 SetBreakLine(ref description);
                 detail.Description = description;
             }
        }
    }
    return pdf;
}
```

View :

```
@model List<Models.Order>
@{
    Layout = null;
 }

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Reports</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/trip")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/datetimepicker")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ajax")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datetimepicker") 
    <style type="text/css">
        table { page-break-inside:auto }
        tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
        thead { display:table-header-group }
        tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img style="margin-top: -7px;" class="img-responsive"    src="~/Content/Images//logo.png" />
    <h1 class="text-center">Reports</h1>
    @Html.Partial("_Index", Model)
</body>
</html>
```

In localhost working but in server, my css and logo not working.

Answer (score 5):

I have spent weeks fighting this issue and I have tried every suggestion Stack Overflow offered:

- Provided custom switches with a username and password for a user created on the IIS Server
- Provided custom switches with a username and password for a user created on the Active Directory (since my application is authenticated through the Active Directory)
- Adjusted permissions for all users to the wkhtmltopdf.exe on the IIS
- Added both .min and normal css files to the bundle list
- Adjusted permissions to the CSS files

In the end I finally removed the bundle reference and specifically stated my CSS file in my layout page header and it worked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Comment: My code looks essentially the same as yours and my styles still aren't rendering in the report locally.  I changed the view bundles to link tags like you did.  The only thing I didn't do is modify permissions to the css files.  I can't imagine that is the issue.  I'm using Rotativa 1.6.4.

Comment: You placed them in the layout page or on the exact page you are trying to render?

Comment: It ended up being the physical path reference.

Answer (score 2):

This situation can occur when your site uses windows authentication.

You need to give access to your CSS files in the web.config as follows:

```
<location path="content">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code.. May this help you

```
@Styles.Render("@Server.MapPath(~/Content/css)")
@Styles.Render("@Server.MapPath("~/Content/trip)")
@Styles.Render("@Server.MapPath("~/Content/datetimepicker)")
@Scripts.Render("@Server.MapPath("~/bundles/jquery)")
@Scripts.Render("@Server.MapPath("~/bundles/ajax)")
@Scripts.Render("@Server.MapPath("~/bundles/modernizr)")
@Scripts.Render("@Server.MapPath("~/bundles/datetimepicker)")
```